# Cannot resolve method create, Android MediaPlayer

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to play a sound when I receive an alarm via the AlaramManager, so in my 
BroadcastReceiver, in the `onReceive` I call my function to play the sound. The only problem is I can't create a Mediaplayer, it throws the `cannot resolve method create` error.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private MediaPlayer mp;



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        PowerManager.WakeLock w1 = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK),"");
        w1.acquire();
        //playSound();
        w1.release();
    }


    public void playSound(){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(AlarmReceiver.this,R.raw.sound);
    }
}
```

I also tried creating the Mediaplayer in the `OnReceive` like so: `mp = MediaPlayer.create(context.this,R.raw.sound);`

But that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

MediaPlayer.create() needs a Context as first parameter. Pass in the current Activity and it should work.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

        PowerManager.WakeLock w1 = pm.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK),"");
        w1.acquire();
        //playSound();
        w1.release();
    }

    public void playSound(){
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound);
    }
}
```